# Imported project crashes immediately -> FATAL EXCEPTION: ...Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, eclipse, fatal-error

Just started working with Android. I imported existing project into eclipse, it crashes immediately when I try to run it with the following error logs:

```
06-05 10:23:38.655: W/dalvikvm(1711): Unable to resolve superclass of Lresearch/diabetes/android/appcore/MobileUnitActivity; (39)
06-05 10:23:38.655: W/dalvikvm(1711): Link of class 'Lresearch/diabetes/android/appcore/MobileUnitActivity;' failed
06-05 10:23:38.655: D/AndroidRuntime(1711): Shutting down VM
06-05 10:23:38.655: W/dalvikvm(1711): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410ef300)
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{research.diabetes.android/research.diabetes.android.appcore.MobileUnitActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: research.diabetes.android.appcore.MobileUnitActivity
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: research.diabetes.android.appcore.MobileUnitActivity
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
06-05 10:23:38.683: E/AndroidRuntime(1711):     ... 11 more
```

I'm not quite sure what is wrong. There are two parts at play: AndroidCore and AndroidUnit_Mobile. The AndroidCore is the meat of the application, where the MobileUnitActivity is located. AndroidUnit_Mobile uses AndroidCore to operate. I have posted manifests for both parts below.

Manifest for AndroidCore:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="research.diabetes.android"
    andrnCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="research.diabetes.android.appcore.ConnectionService" /></application>

</manifest>
```

Manifest for AndroidUnit_Mobile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="research.diabetes.android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="research.diabetes.android.appcore.MobileUnitActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" 
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
                  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="research.diabetes.android.appcore.EmergencyHandler" android:label="EmergencyMode" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name="research.diabetes.android.appcore.EmergencySplashScreen" android:label="EmergencySplashScreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="research.diabetes.android.appcore.ConnectionService" />

         <receiver android:enabled="false" android:name="research.diabetes.android.appcore.DeviceStartIntentReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> 

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What class does MobileUnitActivity extend?

Answer (score 0):

The LogCat says that it can't find your `research.diabetes.android.appcore.MobileUnitActivity` class.  Can you verify that's the right package and class name?